# OnClick how to select deselect background-color of States

Tags: javascript, jquery

Onclick of SVG India Map  if user clicks of any state then that area should be active as background-color "Green", if user clicks on any other state then previous one should be deselect, and new clicked state should active with bg color "Green".

means user can select only 1 state others should be deselect if user clicks on other states.

Hope my question is clear.

here is my working URL:
http://www.acmearchitectural.com/indiamapsvgfiles/map.html

Regards

Comment: You can use snap svg plugin it contains a good api with them. What do you try so far?

Comment: Whats the code that colors the background of states? Or any other js code that you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
$('path[id^="map_"]').click(function(){
$('#regions path').css('fill','');
 $(this).css('fill', "green");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
 $('path[id^="map_"]').click(function(){
   $('path[id^="map_"]').removeAttr('style');$(this).css('fill', "green");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace $(document).ready function with following in your html file.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
       $('path[id^="map_"]').click(function(){
            $('path[id^="map_"]').css('fill', "rgb(235, 236, 237)");
         $(this).css('fill', "green");
       });
     });
```